# only instance methods can be declared @IBAction building audio app

Tags: swift, uikit, swift5, ibaction

I've been trying to build an IOS app that will allow me to click a button and have audio play and I'm getting stuck on this error only instance methods can be declared @IBAction. I've had a search and it doesn't seem like I've closed it out of the class or anything like that but it still doesn't want to work

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
            
class LevelAStartingSoundViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


@IBAction func Sbutton(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        playSound(sound: "Ssound", type: "wav")
    
    
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reformat your code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>), you'll notice that `Sbutton` is *inside* `viewDidLoad`.

[image: Function method is inside viewDidLoad method]

You need to move it outside.

```
@IBAction func sButton(_ sender: UIButton) { /// make sure you have the right function signature
    playSound(sound: "Ssound", type: "wav")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: I've reconfigured my code and I'm now getting this error "Unrecognized selector sent to instance", Screen cap for reference [link](https://imgur.com/a/jS0x6qs)

Comment: @NickSchofield see my edit. Also go to the storyboard, click on your button, then reconnect the `IBAction` using the assistant editor. (You might also need to remove the old one if it exists, you can do that inside the Connections Inspector at last icon in the right panel)